# How to restart OpenStack services after restart/logout?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openstack

I have successfully configured OpenStack following [this](http://ilearnstack.com/2013/04/26/setting-up-a-single-node-openstack-environment/) tutorial.

The problem is that when I logout of my system or restart, and then try to access `OpenStack`' dashboard, it says `page not found`, seems that OpenStack is not started.

I want to know what are the commands to run OpenStack's services?

Answer (score 0):

try devstack (devstack.org) - it is written by the same people who deliver OpenStack, and it is designed to run on your laptop. It works, and you have the benefit of it being exactly the same as OpenStack, because it is backed by the same company (the OpenStack foundation).